# How to Allow my Programs to "Run As" in the Windows start menu?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I notice that some programs on my start menu have the "run as" option while others do not.  It so happens a program I made installed from a msi package does not have this option although I'd like it to.  The properties for this menu entry simply has the name of the program without a path.  I suspect the lack of a path causes the "run as" option to be missing.  Not knowing much about the program I used to create the msi package, MSICREATE, or the structure of such pacakges, I'd appreciate it if someone might point me in the right direction?  I do use orca to transform the msi package.

Comment: Editors:  Should DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS, advanced shortcut, traditional shortcut be added to the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an [advertised shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In WiX it's controlled by the value of the Shortcut/@Advertised attribute; maybe msicreate has something similar?

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a starting point.  I do have stuff in the msi package SHORTCUT table TARGET column of the shortcut in question; supposedly that should generate an advertised shortcut.  There's also the DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS property but I haven't figured out if that is something to do with the installed product or the msi package.

Comment: The article at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Platform-SDK-MSI/29140341/how-to-set-up-shortcut-target-to-point-to-a-real-file.aspx indicates one needs to set DISABLEADVSHORTCUTS=1 in the msi PROPERTY table to get the "run as" option.  I'll try that later today and report back.

Comment: Adding DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1 to the property table gets me the "run as" option.  So the start menu item WITHOUT the "run as" option must be an ADVANCED SHORTCUT while the start menu option with the "run as" option must be a TRADITIONAL non-advanced shortcut.

Comment: Also with DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS=1, the entire path is now shown in the start menu shortcut property.